# Changing template argument implicitely via function attribute without an instance

Tags: c++, performance, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

My problem is, I want a different return type, when using a different type as as an attribute.
If I have something like this:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
  template<typename T>
    inline T& operator[](T)
  {
    ...
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass sc0;
  sc0[SomeType].doSomeThing(); // Error
}
```

It doesn't work because, I need to instantiate SomeType first.
I could of course do this: `sc0[SomeType()].doSomething();`, but that has to reserve memory, thus'll add memory and computational overhead.

I could get rid of the computational overhead by making a static Object of SomeType somewhere, but the memory overhead would still be there.

I also have tried, creating a pointer of type SomeType, without it pointing to anything.
That kinda worked, but every pointer is still 8 Bytes, which is better, than reserving the memory for the full SomeType struct, but I'd still rather not have that.

I know, I could just use `sc0<SomeType>[].doSomeThing();` but that looks ugly and I really want to use the index operator.

Something, that'd also work for what I'm trying to build would be using strings so:

```cpp
...
  template<typename T>
    inline T& operator[](std::string type)
  {
    ...
  }
...
```

I don't think this approach is possible though, as I don't think it's possible to adjust the type of a template based on a function attribute's value.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found *a* way to solve this. Probably something way better out there, I'm just not aware of, but for now, I have defined a `const char _base = 0;`

What that brings me, is that I can reinterpret_cast it to anything I like in a macro: `#define SOME_TYPE (reinterpret_cast<const SomeType&>(_base))` (This doesn't actually add any computational overhead, as reinterpret_cast is only computed at compile time).

Then I can use that macro as a supplement for the type in the Index Operator.
So now the code looks like this:

```cpp
#define SOME_TYPE (reinterpret_cast<const SomeType&>(_base)) // Casts _base into 'const SomeType&', making it 8 bytes, this overhead is only there, whilst the function is getting executed however

const char _base = 0; // 1 Byte in size

class SomeClass
{
  template<typename T>
    inline T& operator[](T)
  {
    ...
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass sc0;
  sc0[SOME_TYPE].doSomeThing(); // 'doSomeThing()' is a method of SomeType
}
```

Comment: As I said, not super happy with this, as there is still overhead, but that's the best I can do for now.